# How do I create an Ubuntu live USB using a Mac?

Tags: live-usb, mac

I'd like to create an Ubuntu live USB stick on a Mac to use to install Ubuntu on another machine. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: there is no need to convert from iso to dmg, the MD5 turned out to be identical prior and after the conversion.

Comment: @Unicycle1234 That is not true. It really needs to be converted.

Comment: Be sure to answer the key point in the question - will it work on another computer (i.e not the macintosh, but rather another machine in need of rescue or install)

Answer (score 82):

Taken from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx):

> We would encourage Mac users to download Ubuntu Desktop Edition by
>   burning a CD. But if you prefer to use a USB stick, please follow the
>   instructions below.
>
> **Note:** this procedure requires that you create an .img file from the .iso file you download. It will also change the filesystem that is
>   on the USB stick to make it bootable, so backup all data before
>   continuing.
>
> **Tip:** Drag and drop a file from Finder to Terminal to 'paste' the full path without risking typing errors.
>
> 1. [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
> 2. Open the Terminal (in `/Applications/Utilities/` or query Terminal in Spotlight)
> 3. Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil. Example:
>
>    ```
>    hdiutil convert -format UDRW ~/path/to/target.iso -o ~/path/to/ubuntu.img
>    ```
>
>    **Note**: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file
>      automatically.
> 4. Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices
> 5. Insert your flash media
> 6. Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media
>      (e.g. `/dev/disk2`)
> 7. Run
>
>    ```
>    diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
>    ```
>
>    (replace `N` with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, `N` would be 2)
> 8. Execute the following command while replacing `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is
>      located; for example, `./ubuntu.img` or `./ubuntu.dmg`).
>
>    ```
>    sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
>    ```
>
>    - Using `/dev/rdisk` instead of `/dev/disk` may be faster.
>    - If you see the error `dd: Invalid number '1m'`, you are using GNU `dd`. Use the same command but replace `bs=1m` with `bs=1M`.
>    - If you see the error `dd:/devdiskN: Resource busy`, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the *Disk Utility.app* and unmount (don't
>        eject) the drive.
> 9. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes
> 10. Restart your Mac and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB-Stick

Comment: Follow-up question: does this process create a USB drive that will boot on a PC, a Mac, or both?

Comment: Works for me on PC

Comment: The linked resources changed quite a bit since this answer. It recommends UNetbootin now.

Comment: FWIW, I was recently (April 2017) trying to use UNetbootin on a Mac.  When it was all ready, the suggested **target** write device, which was the only one available, was not the USB drive at all.  It was a Windows Bootcamp partition on the Mac.  Which would have gotten nuked by the `dd`.  So, don't trust unetbootin blindly, I'll avoid it from now on.  I'll try using this answer instead, at least I get to decide on who's getting **dd'ed**.

Comment: *Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster.*   Not only faster, but since the **rdisk**s are macos "aliases"/synonyms for **r**emovable **disk**, you should have slightly less risk of having `dd` blow away your actual onboard SSD/HD disks.

Comment: The "r" in the "rdisk" device name stands for _raw_, not removable. Access to the disk through that device is unbuffered. That's what it's faster. (There are rdisk devices for internal drives as well.)

Answer (score 22):

You can do it really easily with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which is available for Mac OS - the upside being it doesn't need more than a few clicks on a simple GUI.

(note this is only for newer Intel Mac's, and won't work with older PowerPC machines unfortunately.)

Comment: This works for booting on a PC!  Gooood.

Comment: This is the process suggested by Ubuntu's web site. But it didn't work for me. The app could never see any thumb drive I inserted. There were no instructions for how the thumb drive needed to be formatted, so I tried FAT (which is supposedly Fat32); but had to guess on the other setting (master boot whatever...?). Anyway, the above command-line instructions did work, so I did that.

Answer (score 3):

You could try following the instructions on ubuntu.com.

[How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

### Useful Links

Additionally, you could try looking at some of these links for help:

- [How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick (help.ubuntu.com)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)
- [How To Create A Portable Ubuntu Installation USB On The Mac (makeuseof.com)](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/h-to-croweate-an-ubuntu-installation-usb-on-the-mac/)

Comment: Please don't use the first steps from ubuntu.com. They suggest using Etcher, for some unfathomable reason, which sends data to a remote server even if you opt out. Use the help.ubuntu.com steps or another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the latest Ubuntu ISO from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and UNetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.github.io/).
2. Insert your USB drive.
3. Make UNetbootin executable from file properties.
4. Run it.
5. Now click in *Diskimage*. Give the path of the downloaded Ubuntu ISO.
6. Then select your pen *Drive* from the list.
7. Then press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
8. Wait until finish.

After that you are able to boot or install Ubuntu from that pen-drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linux USB Creator.  The Linux USB Creator for Mac has been released. This is the easiest way to create a live linux USB on a mac.

If you use OSX Lion, you can [Download this file](http://www.mediafire.com/?rctco14mzjayaa9), and if you use OSX Snow Leopard, you can [Download this file](http://www.mediafire.com/?txek9zhxl42k12h)

For more information on the Linux USB creator, just visit the [Website](http://penguintosh.com/)

The other option is to use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

If your Mac is a G4 or G5 take a look at [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2551469?start=0&tstart=0).