# How can i create a bootable usb on mac that is installable on Windows?

Tags: installation, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create an Ubuntu live USB using a Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac)

i'm on a macbook and have an old pc with no operating system on it.
is it possible to create a bootable usb installation for ubuntu that i can 
then use to install it on the pc ?