# trouble installing ubuntu on imac

Tags: system-installation, mac

I have a late model imac 27 with osx mountain lion. I am trying to install ubuntu using virtual box. I have ubuntu 12/64bit on a mac formatted flash drive and on a dvd. The computer doesn't recognize either one of them. States: Fatal error - no bootable disc
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at my [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac/305357#305357), it might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

try to download the ISO of Ubuntu not via HTTP but by using a bittorrent client like transmission and, when the download has finished, burn this ISO.
At least as I have experienced, Bittorrent is a safer way for downloading the ISOs of Ubuntu.