# (two part) Do i need a bootable usb to install ubuntu 13.10 on a os-less computer? and if i do, how do i create one on my mac?

Tags: command-line, 13.10, usb, fat32

i'm fairly sure i need a bootable usb for my new self built computer, but i'm not 100 certain, so i'm asking. and as for how to make a bootable usb, i have a usb in FAT 32 format, and i got stuck on step 3 of the tutorial. After about 2 hours of trying this and looking at other threads, i don't understand any of it. Untill today i had never even opened the terminal on any computer ever so being specific and showing me key-for-key would be very advisable. thanks for the help, i'm really bad at this.

Comment: There are two others ways I know of. Using a CD or DVD; or, you can just send it over the network directly. Sys admins can actually install OSes to 100's of computers over the network this way I hear.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Comment: See if this helps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac/305357#305357

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-

I hope it solves your doubt.

Comment: I already had this link but thanks anyways. I couldnt figure out what i was doing wrong but then i realised that i was typing dhutil instead of hdiutil (such a stupid mistake). But thanks anyway!