# Lost ability to use rEFInd dual boot after updating to Yosemite OSX 10.10

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, refind

I'm no longer able to get access to rEFInd dual boot manager after updating to Yosemite, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by using `efibootmgr`. If you cannot run Ubuntu, use a live version of it.

First make sure you have `efibootmgr` installed

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

Then check the partitions from which EFI can boot

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0082
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Mac OS X
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

In my case it lists 4 partitions. `Boot0000` is the Ubuntu partition where GRUB is installed; by default I want to boot this partition.

I found out that `Boot0080` is the recovery partition of the old Mavericks installation, while `Boot0081` is the Yosemite recovery partition. The partition where Yosemite is *actually* installed, **in my case**, is `Boot0082`.

GRUB is not able to load Mac OS X directly, but I can configure EFI to load the Mac OS X partition when GRUB exits.

So I've run

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0082
```

Which, to recap, means `Boot0000`, where GRUB is installed, will be run first, then if you exit grub (by pressing <kbd>c</kbd> end then typing the command `exit`) you can boot into Mac OS X.

To make the process of booting Mac OS X more comfortable you can add an entry to the GRUB boot menu which exits and thus starts Mac OS X. Just edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and append the following

```
menuentry "Exit to Max OS X" {
  exit
}
```

And reload the GRUB configuration with

```
sudo update-grub
```

All should work.

Comment: This saves my day!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this (now deleted) [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000934/trouble-with-dual-boot-ubuntu-after-update-mac-os-yosemite) (possibly also available [via Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141020163825/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000934/trouble-with-dual-boot-ubuntu-after-update-mac-os-yosemite) and if not here is [a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvCjY.jpg)) by [Ahmad Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4155292/ahmad-afif). The answer uses material from [this Linux Mint Forums tutorial](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1643), which explains that

> - Mac boots Mac OS by default. We need it to boot our GRUB menu instead.
> - GRUB detects Mac OS but doesn't know how to boot it, so we need to fix that as well.

To fix it, [make a live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac) and boot from it, then fix the boot order.

Install and run `efibootmgr`:

```
sudo apt install efibootmgr
efibootmgr
```

One line of the output shows the `BootOrder`, and below that line is a key showing the names of each code, for example

```
BootOrder: 0080, 0000, ...
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS
...
```

To change the order to boot `0000` before `0080`, you can use this command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,80
```

Run `efibootmgr` again to check that the `BootOrder` has changed.

Now GRUB will boot first, and we can use it to boot Ubuntu (or Mint in the case of the tutorial), or, to boot OS X, press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type `exit`. To avoid the latter step in future, it is often sufficient to boot into Ubuntu and run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using rEFIt, you'll have to install rEFInd (I don't think it would work otherwise). The basic steps are:

1. Download rEFInd from http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/
2. Run `./install.sh` form the unzipped folder you've just downloaded
3. Follow the instructions, shutdown (don't restart) and turn it on again.

You may also find this discussion useful: [Cannot boot into Refit (to choose Ubuntu) on Mac after Yosemite Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/542972/48105). This website also provides useful information on that rEFInd is: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/