# How to create a bootable ubuntu USB on a mac without using UNETBOOTIN?

Tags: live-usb, mac, unetbootin

While trying to install Ubuntu on a DELL R720 server the installer flashed a message saying the USB was made using UNETBOOTIN, and it is not recommended. I am trying to find how to make a bootable USB from a mac, and all google links including askubuntu all point to UNETBOOTIN method. So how to create a bootable ubuntu USB on a mac without using UNETBOOTIN?

thank you.

Comment: See this wiki page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick

Comment: thank you, I think this is the page I wasn't able to google find, since it was being crushed by the unetbootin pages in page rank. One other question, all these instructions seem to talk about ubuntu desktop, is there any reason to suspect ubuntu server won't work with the same instructions?

Comment: ok, those instructions are for making a bootable using a mac, to boot a mac. I am trying to use mac to create but then boot a DELL R720 (essentially a PC). Do I just skip the dmg making step and proceed with the rest of the steps?

Answer (score 2):

There's more than a few applications that you can use. I tend to use [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) as personal preference. On a Mac I've used [Mac Linux USB Loader](https://www.sevenbits.io/mlul/).

I would also recommend not letting LiLi auto-fetch the iso file. Download it yourself and link it inside the application. Hope this helps.

Comment: that seems to be specific for windows, do you know any other apps for creating live usb from macs to boot a pc.

Comment: Many apologies, use this: https://www.sevenbits.io/mlul/

Comment: Alternatively, you can use dd in the terminal, as shown here.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac