# Installing Ubuntu on a desktop from .iso downloaded to a Mac

Tags: dell, usb-drive, mac, macosx

I've downloaded the .iso file to my Mac but I cannot open it to generate files to save on a pendrive as a bootable source to a new Dell desktop PC. The PC doesn't boot. It is stuck. I need to reinstall Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Possible duplicates:

 - http://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac
 - http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like "Etcher", multi plattform and more reliable than "Unetbootin". https://etcher.io