# Can't get ubuntu on older mac using el capitan

Tags: mac

The following disk images wouldn't be opened  image: ubuntu -20.04.1  Reason: diskto no mountable file systems

Comment: Correct: It's not a Mac-compatible (.dmg) disk image. It's squashfs. Why do you want to *open* it?

Comment: My Mac is old and very slow.  I read that linux would make it faster & that ubuntu was good for newbies.

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos for what to do with the downloaded .iso.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an Ubuntu live USB using a Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86/how-do-i-create-an-ubuntu-live-usb-using-a-mac)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)